# xTimerIsTimerActive() for Periodic Timer in FreeRTOS

Tags: timer, freertos

I am currently working on FreeRTOS v8.1.2 on Realtek Ameba board and I am using IAR Embedded Workbench IDE.

I am facing a weird issue with `xTimerIsTimerActive()` API of FreeRTOS.
I have a periodic timer and for this periodic timer the `xTimerIsTimerActive()` is always returning True even if I am explicitly stopping and deleting the timer by calling `xTimerStop()` and `xTimerDelete()` actually the code is written in a repeating manner.
But `xTimerIsTimerActive()` also returns True even if the timer is not created and timer handle is initialized NULL.

Sorry I cannot post the code here because it's properitory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call API functions on valid options.  If you call xTimerIsTimerActive() on a [software timer](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-software-timer.html) that has been deleted the object is no longer valid and the behviour undetermined.

Comment: But it is also returning true if I just stop the timer and don't delete it.

Comment: Ok, I came to know the behavior of Timer API's of FreeRTOS. The `xTimerIsTimerActive()` only works for one shot timer which has expired and not for periodic timer which is stopped.